# Hi I am new to Django Framework.getting error :No Module Named

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Users\Nitin\env_mysite\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  119.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "C:\Users\Nitin\env_mysite\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  365.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "C:\Users\Nitin\env_mysite\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  401.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "C:\Users\Nitin\env_mysite\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  395.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "C:\Users\Nitin\env_mysite\lib\importlib\__init__.py" in import_module
  126.     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "C:\Users\Nitin\env_mysite\Scripts\website\website\urls.py" in <module>
  17. from website.views import hello

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: No module named 'website.views'
```

Comment: what exactly is the code you run?

Comment: This is my url file, from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from website.views import hello
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
  url(r'^hello/$',hello),
]

Answer (score 0):

You missed to create the view/ or forget to import views on you url py file. Cross check once again

Comment: I have created the view file and import it in the url file .I have cross checked it.

Comment: from app_name import views
     urlpatterns = [ url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)), url(r'^hello/$', views.hello, 'hello'), ]   , Try Like this .. I will work for you   Refer the main django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial03/  , It will help you

Comment: But i am not able to see in your comment. you should refer django documentation its very easy to learn

Comment: This is my new urls file               from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
  url(r'^$',views.hello,name='hello'),
]